# Garbage characters appear on screen when typing

Tags: terminal, keyboard, suse

When typing, garbage characters somehow appear on the screen for all the letters that I type. The garbage character is a small rectangle box, and this prevents me from executing any commands on the terminal. This happens when I login as root. However, when I log in as a different user, I can type and view the normal characters on the screen. I am using SUSE Linux Professional 10.

Comment: What application are you typing in? If you're tying in a terminal, in what terminal emulator (xterm, gnome-terminal, konsole, …)? What are your language settings (output of the command `locale`)? What characters are you typing?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like it could possibly be a utf-8 (or other international character set) that is not being able to be displayed on your terminal.  Can you check that you have enabled multi-char support and what your LC_LANG variable is set as both your users and root?

Also, what terminal are you using?

Comment: When I check in /etc/sysconfig/language, the setting for LC_LANG is en.US.UTF-8. The terminals that I used are Root Shell -Konsole and Gnome Terminal 2.12.0. I am not sure how to enable multi-char support.

Comment: Check the documentation for Gnome Terminal.  I'm afraid I do not use it.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I manage to get the proper characters back. There is a small keyboard button at the bottom of the terminal screen, and it is not set to English. The problem solved when I chose the correct language. Thank you for your input and assistance.

Comment: You are welcome.  You should consider upvoting and accepting an answer as well -- the latter increases your reputation.